# nav bar opacity issues

Tags: html, css

I am building my first site using bootstrap.  I have an inverse (black) bar running along the top of the page which is my navbar.  Looks great on a laptop, but the navbar goes vertical on small screens, covering the responsive background image I have (a piece of art work).  I want the black bar at the top to be of sufficiently opaqueness to allow the background image to shine through a bit.  I have searched on this topic, but nothing I have tried from previous responses will work.

How the background is deployed:

The nav bar definition:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif" href="#">SITE TITLE</a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href=#>Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Purchase</a><li> 

          </div>
```

Comment: Great.  So we can't edit our screw-ups after we submit a post?

Comment: Yes you can. There is a button in the left bottom corner.

Comment: Did you try using css `opacity: 0.5;`?

Comment: Please edit your post to include a [mcve] using the edit button at the bottom-left corner of the post.

Comment: @nurdyguy I did attempt a .nav { opacity="0.5" !important }  No worky :(

Comment: @RyanTurner If that didn't do anything then something else somewhere is ignoring it.  In Chrome open the console (F12) and inspect the element.  You'll see the css opacity in there with a line through it.  There should be something near it which has an opacity of it.

Comment: Also, which piece has the black background on it?  Can you post the entire css?

Comment: @nurdguy There is no black background.  The 'navbar-inverse' turns the nav bar to black background with grey text.  You can see it here:  http://codepen.io/rhturner/full/XNxMMZ/

Comment: @RyanTurner On that codepen the header is the black bar at the top.  Adding opacity to that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `background-image` to the `body` rather than `html`, then use rgba (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp) to create a translucent `background-colour` by using an alpha channel, rather than using `opacity`. You can do this within a media query so that it only applies to smaller screen devices.

**Note:** Applying opacity to your `nav` affects child elements too, thus your `ul`, including nav text would also become translucent. Using rgba only affects the transparency of the background of a chosen class.

Try this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/3mkajcus/1/